# How can i get value of delay for tap-and-hold on Windows Mobile?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework

How can i get value of delay for tap-and-hold on Windows Mobile? I.e. the delay between tap and the circles being drawn and/or the context menu appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to implement tap-and-hold behaviour in a control which doesn't natively support it you should look into using the [SHRecognizeGesture API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925176.aspx) which handles the entire process (including optional drawing of the dots) automagically.

I have not checked, but according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa926305.aspx) the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\GWE\Commctrl\UseLongDelayForGestures may also be of interest. In the MSDN article this is documented as follows:

> No default setting. This value controls the recognition delay used by SHRecognizeGesture. If this value is set to 1, then the delay is 800 ms. Otherwise, the delay is 400 ms.